# Extend interface defined in .d.ts file

Tags: interface, typescript, extends, definitelytyped

In my TypeScript project, I use [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) definitions for external js dependencies.

Sometimes it might happen that these definitions are outdated. It might also happen than some libraries can add new methods at runtime, like [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) in which you can define custom validator functions.

Therefore I would like to extend those `.d.ts` definitions adding new methods and/or properties.

So if I have my DefinitelyTyped defininiton in `express-validator.d.ts`:

```
declare module ExpressValidator {
  export interface Validator {
    is(): Validator;
    not(): Validator;
    isEmail(): Validator;
    ...
  }
}
```

how can I extend `Validator` interface within, for example, my `application.ts` ?

```
///<reference path='../typings/tsd.d.ts' />

import expressValidator = require('express-validator');
export var app = express();

app.use(expressValidator({
    customValidators: {
        isArray: function(value) {
            return Array.isArray(value);
        }
 }
}));

// How to extend Validator interface adding isArray() method??
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> // How to extend Validator interface adding isArray() method??

You *cannot do this in a file that is a module* ([some guidance here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html)) and your file is a module because you have `import expressValidator`.

Instead create a `extendedValidator.d.ts` and add the new stuff for TypeScript's  engine:

```
declare module ExpressValidator {
  export interface Validator {
     isArray: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do something specific with the `d.ts` file once it is created?  I have done this but I still just get the error that my new property doesn't exist.  Do I have to put it in a specific location or do something else to get it recognized by the compiler?

Comment: @basarat do you have to "export" the interface? is that required? what happens when you don't export?

Comment: @MohamedNuur you have to export it if you want to make it publicly available.

Comment: @NoNameProvided clarified it for me in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687894/typescript-d-ts-syntax-export-and-declare/41695486#41695486 -- hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to accomplish this by following the directions at https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-solutions/typescript-adding-custom-type-definitions-for-existing-libraries/. There they use the example of `react`.

```
import 'react';
 
declare module 'react' {
    interface OlHTMLAttributes<T> {
        type?: "1" | "a" | "A" | "i" | "I";
    }
}
```

I found this works really well for `winston` too.

Comment: Thank you so much. All i needed was importing the module at the top of the `.d.ts` file