# Adding typescript type definitions to jquery outside of jquery.d.ts

Tags: jquery, typescript

In an external .ts file I am adding a method to jquery like so:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
  //do stuff
  return stuff;
};
```

I would like to add this new method to the typescript definitions for jquery from within this file, rather than adding it to jquery.d.ts, in this way I will maintain this new method definition even if I update jquery and it's type definition file later.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, just add it to a separate definition file, that imports the definitions from jquery.d.ts, and adds your new method to the JQuery type.

Comment: Surprisingly that works even if files point at jquery.d.ts and not my new file! Feel free to make that an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, I know it will pick up anything in any .d.ts files you have, referenced or not.

Comment: That is convenient at the moment but seems like potentially bad!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948271/extend-interface-defined-in-d-ts-file