# How can I extend an existing interface when the definitions require an import statement?

Tags: typescript

I've created a custom Knockout extender, and I'm having trouble extending the existing interface provided by a definition file for Knockout.

**Extenders/Numeric.ts**

```
import * as ko from "knockout";

function Extender(target: KnockoutObservable<number>, options: IOptions = {}): KnockoutObservable<number> {
    // ...
};

interface IOptions {
    // ...
}

export {Extender as NumericExtender, IOptions as INumericExtenderOptions}
```

**Boot.ts**

```
import * as ko from "knockout";
import {NumericExtender} from "./Extenders/Numeric";

class Boot {    
    public constructor() {
        ko.extenders.numeric = NumericExtender;
    }
}
```

To let the compiler about `ko.extenders.numeric`, I need to extend the existing interface:

```
interface KnockoutExtenders {
    numeric(target: KnockoutObservable<number>, options?: INumericExtenderOptions): KnockoutObservable<number>;
}
```

Now here I run into trouble. In order to access `INumericExtenderOptions`, I need an `import` statement:

```
import {INumericExtenderOptions} from "./Extenders/Numeric";
```

But when an import statement is added, the file is considered to be a module, [which makes it impossible to extend an existing interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32959534/247702).

Is there a way to do this, or will I need to move `IOptions` to the definition file in order to avoid an `import`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using the global version of the knockout declaration file. I don't think it is possible to extend an interface defined in the global scope from within a module declaration file. There are several solutions:

- I think the easiest solution is to **put your interface into the global namespace** as well. For IOptions this becomes:

  ```
  // index.d.ts
  interface IOptions {
    // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  }

  interface KnockoutExtenders {
    numeric(target: KnockoutObservable<number>, options?: IOptions): KnockoutObservable<number>;
  }
  ```

  Now you can access IOptions and KnockoutExtenders with a numeric function anywhere, as the declaration file is still global.
- Another solution would be to **pull in the module version** (I think this is my preferred solution, just because your not polluting the global namespace with all the knockout types). In the case of knockout: `typings install --save knockout`. Then you would have to specifically import the types you need, whenever you need them. Eg. your numeric.ts becomes

  ```
  // src/numeric.ts
  import { Observable } from "knockout"

  export function Extender(target: Observable<number>, options: IOptions = {}): Observable<number> {
    // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  };

  export interface IOptions {
    // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  }
  ```

  Then you can augment the knockout module in another declaration file. eg:

  ```
  // index.d.ts
  import { Observable } from "knockout"
  import { IOptions } from './src/numeric'

  declare module "knockout" {
    interface Extenders {
      numeric(target: Observable<number>, options?: IOptions): Observable<number>
    }
  }
  ```

  Then you should be able to use the augmented Extenders interface anywhere in your application:

  ```
  // src/boot.js
  import { extenders } from "knockout"
  import { Extender } from "./numeric"

  class Boot {
    public constructor() {
      extenders.numeric = Extender
    }
  }
  ```
- A final solution, probably best solving your problem, is to use a modular declaration file, but to **augment the global module**. Your numeric.ts stays the same, and your declaration file becomes:

  ```
  import { IOptions } from './src/numeric'

  declare global {
    interface KnockoutExtenders {
      numeric(target: KnockoutObservable<number>, options?: IOptions): KnockoutObservable<number>
    }
  }
  ```

For more information, have a look at the [page on declaration merging from the typescript handbook.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: Managed to find some time to go over this, I ended up using the third solution. There's no module version of Knockout available at this time, so the second solution didn't work for this case.

Comment: Weird. `typings install knockout` for sure installs a module knockout declaration file. But maybe this is not the file that you want?

Comment: I mean the actual library :) not the typings. Unless I misunderstand things and there's a way to "modularize" a library?

Comment: Same with me, third solution's great! Exactly what I needed. (and odd it isn't mentioned in more places)