# Overriding TypeScript definitions extended by other libraries

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've run into several cases where one library extends another library, particularly in my uses with React and Redux.

As an example, say I was using a JS library that exported a function that could be defined like this:

```
function dispatch(action:IAction):void;

interface IAction {
    type: string;
}
```

And I use another JS library that enhances the `dispatch` function to allow callbacks, which could be defined like this:

```
function dispatch(action:IAction | IActionCallback):void;

interface IActionCallback {
    (dispatch:IDispatch):void;
}
```

The problem is that the second library augments the first library. How can this be properly expressed in typings? Or can it be?

Answer (score 0):

So what you would do is have the declaration file of the extending library 'augment' the original library.

The [redux-thunk declaration file](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/index.d.ts#L7-L11) does almost exact that: it augments the `Dispatch` interface of redux.

For more information, [I wrote a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786222/how-can-i-extend-an-existing-interface-when-the-definitions-require-an-import-st/38986434#38986434) on the different possibilities if you want to augment another module, depending on whether your declaration file needs to be global. Or have a look at the [page on declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) from the typescript handbook.

If you have any more questions, I'm happy to help .

Comment: Thanks, still trying to digest this... the problem I'm having here with Redux Thunk is that if I `import {IDispatch} from "redux"` it doesn't seem to know about the redux-thunk enhancement to allow functions to be actions. It only works if I `import {IDispatch} from "~redux-thunk~redux"` which is odd an I'm not sure the right way to import something, since that isn't a real module.