# Add Properties to the interface from within an NPM module

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function that provides a basic functionality like this one:

```
// File 1: Core function
export const extensions = [];
export interface ResultInterface {
     fullname:string,
     age:number
}

function maFunction():ResultInterface {
    var o = {
         fullname:"alex",
         age:21
    };
    extensions.forEach((extension) => o = extension(o));
    return o;
}
```

As you can see from the code above the `maFunction` is extensible by looking through the `extensions` array and applying those functions.

For example, one can install the following extensions through NPM:

```
// File 2: Extensions 1 (installed via NPM)
extensions.push(function (o) {
    o.ageInMonths = o.age * 12;
    return o;
});


// File 3: Extensions 2 (installed via NPM)
extensions.push(function (o) {
    o.firstname = o.fullname.split(" ")[0];
    o.lastname = o.fullname.split(" ")[1];
});
```

Now in the userland:

```
// File 4: Userland execution
var myVar = maFunction();

myVar.ageInMonths // error: Property 'ageInMonths' does not exist on type 'ResultInterface'.
myVar.firstname // error: Property 'firstname' does not exist on type 'ResultInterface'.
myVar.lastname // error: Property 'lastname' does not exist on type 'ResultInterface'.
```

I didn't expect typeScript to be smart enough to detect the properties added via the extensions. But how can each extension add them manually? how can each extension extend the `ResultInterface` and add it's own properties?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is it possible to do this without modifying the .d.ts of `ResultInterface` (see so response here: [Extend interface defined in .d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948271/extend-interface-defined-in-d-ts-file))

What you could do tho' is use [Intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to type `myVar` and augment it's interface with the functions you need:

```
var myVar: ResultInterface & {ageInMonths: number, firstname: string, lastname: string} = maFunction();
```

You could add a "type shortcut" like this:

```
type ResultInterfaceAugmented = {ageInMonths: number, firstname: string, lastname: string}& ResultInterface;
var myVar: ResultInterfaceAugmented = maFunction();
```