# Extend DefinitelyTyped .d.ts definitions

Tags: typescript, interface, extends, nightmare, definitelytyped

I try to use [nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) in typescript with the types from DefinitelyTyped. however, the types there are incomplete (the `then` method is missing) and I also want to add dynamically some methods (as it is done in [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare-har-plugin)).

I don't understand how to extend the interface of Nightmare without forking DefinitelyTyped. I have read a few pages about these question:

[Extend interface defined in .d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948271/extend-interface-defined-in-d-ts-file)

http://obaidurrehman.github.io/2015/10/30/extending-typeScript-definitions/

So I tried to create a `extendNightmare.d.ts` file that I put along all my other `.ts` files.

```
declare namespace Nightmare {
  class Nightmare {
    waitForDevTools(): void;
    then(): Nightmare;
  }
}
```

At this point, I don't know what to do to tell the compiler to use my new definition that is supposed to extend the existing one.

I tried to add this line at the top of the file using nightmare but it didn't work:

```
/// <reference path="./extendNightmare.d.ts"/>
```

Also I would like to extend the interface `IConstructorOptions` from the `Nightmare` namespace, but I don't know how to do so. Is this correct?

```
declare namespace Nightmare {
  class Nightmare {
    waitForDevTools(): void;
    then(): Nightmare;
  }

  export interface IConstructorOptions {
    switches: any;
  }
}
```

The code I'm using to reproduce this issue:

```
/// <reference path="./extendNightmare.d.ts"/>

import * as Nightmare from "nightmare";

const switches = {
  "ignore-certificate-errors": true,
  "proxy-server": "localhost:10000",
};

function render_page(url) {
  const options = {
    switches,
  };

  const nightmare = new Nightmare(options);

  nightmare
  .goto(url)
  .then((infos) => {
    console.info(infos);
  })
  .end()
  .then(() => {
    console.info(`${url}: done`);
  });
}

render_page("https://google.com");
```

In my `package.json`, I have:

```
"nightmare": "^2.9.1",
"@types/nightmare": "^1.6.30",
```

Comment: Just FYI, the module keyword is deprecated for declaring a namespace. Use the `namespace` keyword instead.

Comment: can you post the code that use the extended defintions.

Comment: Sure. I added the code to the original post.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I moved to pupeteer instead of nightmare, never digged this problem too much.