# how to add functions to CanvasRenderingContext2D prototype in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to add a function on CanvasRenderingContext2D. what it does is to draw a circle text.

in javascript, all I need to do is write code like this:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillTextCircle = function () {
    //some code       
}
```

however it desen't work in typescript.

I also try these two methods:

1.
  add following code at the file header

```
interface CanvasRenderingContext2D {
    fillTextCircle: any;
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillTextCircle = function () {
    //some code       
}
```

2.
 add this line in lib.dom.d.ts

```
interface CanvasRenderingContext2D extends CanvasState, CanvasTransform, CanvasCompositing, CanvasImageSmoothing, CanvasFillStrokeStyles, CanvasShadowStyles, CanvasFilters, CanvasRect, CanvasDrawPath, CanvasUserInterface, CanvasText, CanvasDrawImage, CanvasImageData, CanvasPathDrawingStyles, CanvasTextDrawingStyles, CanvasPath {
    readonly canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    fillTextCircle: any;   //add this line in lib.dom.d.ts
}
```

but it still complains this error:

> Property 'fillTextCircle' does not exist on type
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.

Comment: Please check other questions, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948271/extend-interface-defined-in-d-ts-file).

Comment: all right,I got it ! so I cannot modified the interface directly in lib.dom.d.ts.but I create a global.d.ts and add the following code:
`
interface CanvasRenderingContext2D {
    fillTextCircle: any;
}
 
`  It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a global.d.ts,and add the following code:

```
 interface CanvasRenderingContext2D {
    fillTextCircle: any;
}
```

It will work

[link question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948271/extend-interface-defined-in-d-ts-file)