# Typescript: How to augment `export = Joi.Root`

Tags: typescript, joi

Types for `@hapi/joi` seem to be outdated - some configuration params mentioned in the official documentation are missing in the types. So I am trying to augment the types.

*node_modules/@types/hapi__joi/index.d.ts*:

```
declare namespace Joi {
...
interface ErrorFormattingOptions {...}
...
interface Root {...}
}

declare const Joi: Joi.Root;
export = Joi;
```

One of my .ts source files:

```
import joi from '@hapi/joi'

declare global {
  namespace Joi {
    interface ErrorFormattingOptions {
      wrap?: {
        label?: string | false
        array?: string | false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That doesn't work

```
type R = Joi.ErrorFormattingOptions['']//autocomplete show only my 'wrap'
```

What is the proper way of augmentation in this case? Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Looks like that's impossible. Module `'@hapi/joi'` has no named export `ErrorFormattingOptions`. And in Typescript one cannot augment what's not exported

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32959534/2308005

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extend interface defined in .d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948271/extend-interface-defined-in-d-ts-file)

Comment: No, moving `declare global  namespace Joi` to separate .d.ts file didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Closest I've come to extend augment joi is adding a new method

joi-objectid.d.ts

```
declare module 'joi-objectid' {
  import Joi from 'joi';

  function objectId(): Joi.AlternativesSchema;

  function joiObjectId(joi: Joi.Root, message?: string): typeof objectId;

  export = joiObjectId;
}
```

joi.d.ts

```
import joiObjectId from 'joi-objectid';

declare module 'joi' {
  interface Root {
    objectId(): joiObjectId;
  }
}
```

Similarly you could try augment `ErrorFormattingOptions` interface directly on `joi` module and not overriding the one loaded onto the global scope I guess.